# Positioning the Legend Box

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a bar Plot that looks like this:
[image]

If I use the command `legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1)` then I get the plot like this:
[image]

But in this case the legend overlaps the plot. I want that the legend just shifts upwards without overlapping as in the first plot. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
theme(legend.justification = "top")
```

Example:

```
mtcars$gear = factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl = factor(mtcars$cyl)
p = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=gear, fill=cyl) ) + geom_bar()
p = p + xlab("Gears") + ggtitle("Cylinders by Gears")
p = p + theme(legend.justification = "top")

p
```

Comment: Ohh it worked. Actually I was using `legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification="top"` together due to which it was not aligning properly. When I used just  `legend.justification = "top"` it got fixed. Thanks.